# how to enable read and fd_cloexec at the same time when using popen()

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I'd like to open a pipe with `read` and `fd_cloexec` at the same time, however, I cannot figure out how to set the second parameter of the `popen()` function, there is still a file descriptor for the pipe in the child process if running the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *p=popen("ls -l","re");
   char buf[100];
   memset(buf,0x00,100);

   fread(buf,sizeof(char),10,p);

   if (fork()==0)
   {
      while(1)
      {
      }
   }

   printf("%s",buf);
   pclose(p);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the `e` modifier is a feature of glibc 2.9; on older versions it will have no effect.  What standard library version are you using?

Comment: i'm using some newer version than 2.9, so i think it wont be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Not all versions of `popen` support the `e` modifier.  To make it work in general, you'll need to set the CLOEXEC flag on the file descriptor manually:

```
FILE *p = popen("ls -l", "r");
fcntl(fileno(p), F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

Comment: Actually I have testet this today and its not working. The file descriptor of the pipe is available in the child process.